# mySQL Query code and indexing optimisation

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, query-optimization

I have the following query on an 8 million rows mySQL table that takes 24 seconds to run.

Could you pleas advise me:

1. how to optimise the SQL code
2. which indexes are the best on the table

Thanks in advance

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN (`Data ultima attestazione` >= '2016-12-25' AND Operatore = 'XXX') THEN 'Attestato nell''ultimo mese'
        WHEN (`Data ultima attestazione` < '2016-12-25' AND `Data ultima attestazione` != '' AND Operatore = 'XXX') THEN 'Non Attestato fino a 6 mesi'
        WHEN (`Data ultima attestazione` = '' AND Operatore = 'XXX') THEN 'Silente'
        WHEN Operatore = 'CESS' THEN 'Cessato'
        WHEN Operatore = 'FFF' THEN 'Passato a FFF'
        WHEN Operatore = 'VVV' THEN 'Passato a VVV'
        WHEN Operatore = 'WWW' THEN 'Passato a WWW'
        WHEN Operatore = 'HHH' THEN 'Passato a HHH'
        WHEN Operatore = 'PPP' THEN 'Passato a PPP'
        WHEN Operatore = 'CCC' THEN 'Passato a CCC'
        WHEN Operatore = 'TTT' THEN 'Passato a TTT'
        WHEN Operatore = 'NNN' THEN 'Passato a NNN'
        WHEN Operatore = 'LLL' THEN 'Passato a LLL'
        ELSE 'Silente'
    END As Stato,
    SUM(CASE WHEN `Tipizzazione` = 'UUU'
             THEN 1
             ELSE 0
        END
    ) As UUU,
    SUM(CASE WHEN `Tipizzazione` = 'NUU'
             THEN 1
             ELSE 0
        END
    ) As NUU,
    SUM(CASE WHEN `Tipizzazione` = 'LSC'
             THEN 1
             ELSE 0
        END
    ) As LSC,
    COUNT(NTT) As NTT
FROM RETE_ANAGRAFICA_UTENZE_SENZA_SERVIZI
WHERE TERR LIKE '%'
  AND AREA like '%' 
  AND STRUTTURA_VENDITA like '%' 
  AND CF like '%'
GROUP BY Stato
ORDER BY Totale DESC;
```

Comment: Pls provide the results of the explain of the query, also the list of existing indexes and the fields the indexes are defined on.

Comment: The issue is the way which you have structured the DB, also why the multiple like '%' queries?

Comment: Karan, it is a store procedure: the '%' are normally parameters, that can be '%' in the worst case

Answer (score 0):

You have no filtering (`LIKE '%'`), so you are asking to look at all 8M rows.  It takes time to read and process that much data; 24 seconds is not unreasonable.  No indexes with help.

If you sometimes have filtering, then consider this:

- An index might help with `LIKE 'abc%'
- No index can help with `LIKE '%abc'` or `LIKE '%abc%'`.
- You may need 3 indexes:  `INDEX(AREA), INDEX(STRUTTURA_VENDITA), INDEX(CF)`.

If the schema is amenable to having a [Summary Table](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables), that would provide a way to improve performance.

Comment: Don't you think the case-when have an impact in the performance? Yes the LIkE '%' are often LIKE 'ABC'. So you think it is better to have 3 seperate indexes instead of an index with the 3 columns?

Comment: `INDEXes` are use from the left; if it can't use the first column (eg, because of a leading wildcard), then the index is useless.  [_Index Cookbook_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).  Complicated expression (`CASE or worse) in the `SELECT` part have very little impact on the overall performance.

Answer (score 0):

You should include a parameter to speed up the filter when you want search for all records

```
WHERE (@search_terr = 0 OR TERR LIKE @search_terr_txt)
  AND (@search_area = 0 OR AREA like @search_area_txt
  AND (@search_stru = 0 OR STRUTTURA_VENDITA like @search_strut_txt
  AND (@search_cf   = 0 OR CF like @search_cf_txt
GROUP BY Stato
ORDER BY Totale DESC;
```